"Maximum recursive updates" calling luxon Duration.toFormat from a property in vue
When I call toFormat() on a Duration property in a Vue component, it throws Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component <App>
with:
"dependencies": {
    "luxon": "^3.4.4",
    "vue": "^3.4.21"
  }

when I:
<template>
    <div>{{entry.duration.toFormat("hh:mm:ss")}}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive } from 'vue'
import { Duration } from 'luxon'

class Entry {
  public get duration() { return Duration.fromMillis(20000) }
}

const entry = reactive(new Entry())
</script>

I get:
<div>00:00:20</div>

But I also get
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of app errorHandler
Uncaught (in promise) Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component <App>. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

If I move toFormat to the property getter, I don't get the error:
<div>{{entry.duration}}</div>
...
public get duration() { return Duration.fromMillis(20000).toFormat("hh:mm:ss") }

If I change the property to a function, I don't get the error:
<div>{{entry.duration().toFormat("hh:mm:ss")}}</div>
...
public duration() { return Duration.fromMillis(20000) }

Does this mean that toFormat is mutating the Duration object?
If so, that would be a bug in Luxon as it's supposed to be immutable.

Might be an interesting read: https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/1104#issuecomment-1001835217 Looks like it can bypass immutability under some circumstances. Looking at older issues, looks like some functions from Luxon were immutable (by error I think) but that might still be a thing under some specific conditions, since you're using classes might be the issue.
